# How do I make my variable available inside an assets loop?

Tags: assets, variable, forloop, set

I have an entries field called 'customerLogoBarUrl'. It contains one entry. So I can do this:

```
{% for item in entry.customerLogoBarUrl.limit(1) %}
  {% set theUrl = item.url %}
{% endfor %}
```

But then I need to output that variable inside an assets loop:

```
{% for item in entry.customerLogoBar %}
  {% for asset in item.logo %}
    <a href="{{ theUrl }}"><img src="{{ asset.url() }}"></a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This yields *theUrl doesn't exist*.

Comment: A few questions: Is there a reason you're using an Entries field (customerLogoBarUrl ) to define a URL and not something like a text field? In your 2nd example, is `customerLogoBar` supposed to be `customerLogoBarUrl` or do you have two fields? If the latter, what type of field is `customerLogoBar`?

Comment: @BradBell I'm using an entries field in `customerLogoBarUrl` because I need to create a relationship to the entry. `customerLogoBar` is a separate assets field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a [scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) issue. You've defined `theUrl` inside the scope of a `for` loop, so it only ever lives inside of that loop.

You can do this to have it exist outside of the loop, too.

```
{% set theUrl = '' %}

{% for item in entry.customerLogoBarUrl.limit(1) %}
    {% set theUrl = item.url %}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in entry.customerLogoBar %}
    {% for asset in item.logo %}
        <a href="{{ theUrl }}"><img src="{{ asset.url() }}"></a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have to define `{{ the Url }}` prior to looping through the assets field, as it comes from a different field.

Comment: Ohh... so your 2nd example isn't a replacement of your first.  It's in addition to it.  My bad, will update answer.